# Big Query - Transpose arrays into colums

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-processing

We have a table in Big Query like below.

Input table:

```
 Name | Interests
 -----+----------
 Bob  | ["a"]
 Sue  | ["a","b"]
 Joe  | ["b","c"]
```

We want to convert the above table to below format to make it BI/Visualisation friendly.

Target/Required table:

```
 +------------------+
 | Name | a | b | c |
 +------------------+
 | Bob  | 1 | 0 | 0 |
 | Sue  | 1 | 1 | 0 |
 | Joe  | 0 | 1 | 0 |
 +------------------+
```

**Note:** The Interests column is an array datatype. Is this sort of transformation possible in Big Query? If yes, Any reference query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and uses scripting features of BQ

```
#standardSQL
create temp table ttt as (
  select name, interest 
  from `project.dataset.table`, 
  unnest(interests) interest
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
  SELECT name, """ || 
    STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(interest = '""" || interest || """', 1, 0)) AS """ || interest, ', ') 
  || """
  FROM ttt 
  GROUP BY name
  """
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT interest 
    FROM ttt
    ORDER BY interest
  )
);
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Getting the following error while executing your query:
```Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string ` SELECT userID, MAX(IF(interest = '"art_and_theatre"', 1, 0)) AS "art_and_theatre", MAX(IF(interest = '"books"', 1, 0)) AS "books", .... FROM ttt GROUP BY userID `, Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "art_and_theatre" at [7:19]```


Sample Raw data:
 ```[
  {
    "userID": "\"qX8PnOOEkVelDapncOrse0UXQMA3\"",
    "interest": [
      "\"music\""
    ]
  },
  {
    "userID": "\"aQDSPoeP9bRYUktsGGxiJkOfELt2\"",
    "interest": [
      "\"fashion_and_beauty\""
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: have you tried first to run above script against sample data you provided in your question? I tested it with the data you provided and it perfectly works! so in order to figure out your problem - let's first try with data you provided in the question. please try and let know result. And also make sure you are not changing anything in the script I provided !!!

Comment: Yes. That seems to be working fine. But when I apply it to my real data, it is throwing the above error. I have given the sample records above. Any thoughts about why it is failing?

Comment: ok. good sign. so looks like your data has extra quotes in it. try replace this line `STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(interest = '""" || interest || """', 1, 0)) AS """ || interest, ', ') ` with this one `STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(interest = '""" || interest || """', 1, 0)) AS """ || REPLACE(interest, '"', ''), ', ') `

Comment: That worked! But the results seem to be wrong. All of the interests are getting 0's for the user IDs.

Comment: see my above comment - about typo!! and the rest of comment too :o)

Comment: Got it. Let me try.

Comment: sure. glad you made it. see you in next posts :o)

Comment: quick question: The above query is failing if the interests column is empty. Any workaround for that?

Comment: what exactly you mean by empty? null? or else? and what you tried? you should apply little efforts too! :o)

Comment: The issue is not because of an empty value. It seems like a few of the rows in the interests column is having JSON objects. We will have to fix it at the source level.
On the other hand, How can we create an actual table with the above results? I see now it is creating a temp table... How to create a permanent table/view?

Comment: You can add insert table statement to select query so result will be inserted into the table. In case of any more question(s) - please post new question with all relevant details and I will be happy to answer. This current question I consider fully answered already!

Comment: Posted a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64383628/7463780