# Big Query - Create a table/view from a temp table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

We have a query in Big Query like below

```
CREATE temp table ttt as (
  SELECT * FROM TABLE
);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  ---Dynamic query goes here--- 
);
```

The above query is storing the results in a temporary table as written in the query. How to store these results into an actual table/view so that it can be utilized for further data modelling?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (concat('create table dataset.table as ',---Dynamic query goes here---)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a persistent table in the first place? Or could you save the results after `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` using query below?

```sql
CREATE TABLE yourDataset.ttt as (
  SELECT * FROM ttt
);
```

Comment: This is storing the _ttt_ table AS IS. The dynamic changes in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` are not getting reflected in the output table.

Answer (score 0):

As I already suggested you in your previous question - just add `CREATE TABLE your_table AS` or `INSERT your_table` as in below example. Use [CREATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement) (DDL) or [INSERT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_statement) (DML) depends on do you need to create new table or insert into existing one

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  CREATE TABLE dataset.table AS
  SELECT ---Rest of your dynamic query goes here--- 
);
```