# Big Query - Transpose Specific fields into Columns

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have a table in Big Query like below.

Input table:

```
 Name | Question  | Answer
 -----+-----------+-------
 Bob  | Interest  | a     
 Sue  | Interest  | a
 Sue  | Interest  | b
 Joe  | Interest  | b
 Joe  | Gender    | Male
 Bob  | Gender    | Female
 Sue  | DOB       | 2020-10-17
```

We want to convert the above table to the below format to make it BI/Visualisation friendly.

Target/Required table:

```
 +----------------------------------------+
 | Name | a | b | c | Gender | DOB        |
 +----------------------------------------+
 | Bob  | 1 | 0 | 0 | Female | 2020-10-17 |
 | Sue  | 1 | 1 | 0 |   -    |     -      |
 | Joe  | 0 | 1 | 0 |  Male  |     -      |
 +----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for **BigQuery Standard SQL** and **does not depend** on knowing specific questions and generic enough for any values of questions and answers

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
    SELECT name, """ || STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(answer = '""" || value || """', 1, 0)) AS """ || value, ', ')   
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT answer value FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE question = 'Interest' ORDER BY value
)) || (
  SELECT ", " || STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(question = '""" || value || """', answer, '-')) AS """ || value, ', ')   
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT question value FROM `project.dataset.table`
    WHERE question != 'Interest' ORDER BY value
)) || """  
  FROM `project.dataset.table` 
  GROUP BY name
  """;
```

Comment: sorry but I cannot see how the requirement is so complex that you need either dynamic sql or multiple `select distinct` statements

Comment: @Used_By_Already - I totally disagree with you! think wide and see far then just particular example!!! when you will learn to do so  - come and judge! or better just provide your answer. But downvoting correct answer - just because of you don't see something - is quite low!! I recommend you to re-read my answer - especially first sentence - so maybe you will get it and change your mind and withdraw your downvote

Comment: Although this might be overkill for the simple case OP is showing, this is technically correct.

Comment: let's see for what OP will say - from experience - usually while sample data consists of just few values to pivot - the real case has 10s or 100s - and in such cases  - solution presented in my answer is the only way to go! so I really don't understand why you would resist to use right direction and why you would qualify it as a overkill! Also the trick in this case is that it was two different pivots - which make it quite different from all/any previous pivot related questions here on SO - art least for google-bigquery tag

Comment: @mikhail  Since we have multiple pivots in the query, How storing the final results to a table works in this case?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I upvoted the answer by Gordon Linoff instead of adding my own which would have been ridiculously similar, but I have now included a variant answer which adds the dashes in the output. All with a single easy to maintain select statement using conditional aggregates - simple and easy to follow.

Comment: @Used_By_Already - simple and easy -  but useless for real practical use case! i am surprised you still not realized this

Comment: @Gopal - `How storing the final results to a table works in this case?` - this is already answered - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394176/5221944

Comment: @mikhail I have tried this. But getting `Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CREATE at [2:3]`

Comment: @Gopal - this question is fully answered. if you still have comments on another post - please do it in that post and we can address whatever issue you still have

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       countif(question = 'Interest' and answer = 'a') as a,
       countif(question = 'Interest' and answer = 'b') as b,
       countif(question = 'Interest' and answer = 'c') as c,
       max(case when question = 'gender' then answer end) as gender,
       max(case when question = 'DOB' then answer end) as dob
from t
group by name;
```

Note:  This returns `NULL` when the values are missing. To me, that makes more sense than `'-'`, although the logic could be tweaked to return hyphens instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `coalesce()` will supply the dashes without the complexity (and weaknesses) of dynamic sql and multiple selects. Note this is merely a variant of the answer by Gordon Linoff - I simply added the logic for dashes instead of NULL.

```
select name,
       countif(question = 'Interest' and answer = 'a') as a,
       countif(question = 'Interest' and answer = 'b') as b,
       countif(question = 'Interest' and answer = 'c') as c,
       coalesce(max(case when question = 'gender' then answer end),'-') as gender,
       coalesce(max(case when question = 'DOB' then answer end),'-') as dob
from t
group by name;
```