# Dynamic column names in bigquery procedure

Tags: dynamic, google-bigquery, procedure

How can I dynamically assign the Column Names in Bigquery Procedure. I have a counter declared in my procedure:

```
DECLARE counter int64 default 1;
```

And in the procedure, I use while loop to keep self joining till the time there are no more parents remaining. My only question is to determine a way to find the dynamic column names. like manager_id_{@counter} based on the hierarchy available.

I have the following tables available:

Table 1:

| emp_id | manager_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 10 | 10 |
| 20 | 10 |
| 30 | 20 |

My Output:

| emp_id | manager_id | manager_id_1 | manager_id_2 | manager_id_3 | manager_id_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | NULL |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 20 | 10 | 10 | 20 | NULL | NULL |
| 30 | 20 | 10 | 20 | 30 | NULL |

I am able to come up with the logic, the only missing piece is the column name. I saw many posts which were related to SQL and other DBMS. But couldn't find something for BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE counter int64 default 1;
execute immediate "Select " || 5 || " as manager_id_" || counter
```

Comment: I am trying this thing in procedure. This doesn't work in the CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE in Procedure

Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword SELECT or keyword WITH but got keyword EXECUTE at [39:5]

Comment: @NewCoder Could you please provide your query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383628/big-query-create-a-table-view-from-a-temp-table

Answer (score 0):

The way I resolved it was using Jinja like scripting.