# Big Query - Transpose array/json objects into columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This question is a continuation of these two:

1. [Big Query - Transpose arrays into colums](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64346504/7463780)
2. [Big Query - Transpose Specific fields into Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64398312/7463780)

We have a table in Big Query like below.

**Input table:**

```
 Name | Question  | Answer
 -----+-----------+-------
 Bob  | Interest  | ["a"]     
 Sue  | Interest  | ["a", "b"]
 Joe  | Interest  | ["b"]
 Joe  | Gender    | Male
 Bob  | Gender    | Female
 Sue  | DOB       | 2020-10-17
 Bob  | Others    | { "country" : "es", "language" : "ca"}
```

**Note:** All the values in the Answer column are stringified values and the Arrays / JSON objects are dynamic.

We want to convert the above table to the below format to make it BI/Visualisation friendly.

**Desired table:**

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Name | a | b | c | Gender | DOB        | country | language |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Bob  | 1 | 0 | 0 | Female | 2020-10-17 |   es    |   ca     |
 | Sue  | 1 | 1 | 0 |   -    |     -      |   -     |   -      |
 | Joe  | 0 | 1 | 0 |  Male  |     -      |   -     |   -      |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: have you tried at least something by yourself? you have already almost everything answered already, just a little extra efforts needed! so have you tried? what the problem(s) you got?

Comment: @mikhail I could extract the JSON values using JSON_EXTRACT functions. But extracting them dynamically and converting them into a separate columns is where I got stuck.

Comment: i see. anyway - see the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
create temp table data as
select name, question, value as answer 
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(split(translate(answer, '[]" ', ''))) value
where question = 'Interest'
union all
select name, question, answer 
from `project.dataset.table`
where not question in ('Interest', 'Others')
union all
select name, 
  split(value, ':')[offset(0)] as question, 
  split(value, ':')[offset(1)] as answer 
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest(split(translate(answer, '{}" ', ''))) value
where question = 'Others';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
  SELECT """
    SELECT name, """ || STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(answer = '""" || value || """', 1, 0)) AS """ || value, ', ')   
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT answer value FROM data
  WHERE question = 'Interest' ORDER BY value
)) || (
  SELECT ", " || STRING_AGG("""MAX(IF(question = '""" || value || """', answer, '-')) AS """ || value, ', ')   
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT question value FROM data
    WHERE question != 'Interest' ORDER BY value
)) || """  
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY name
  """;
```

if to apply to sample data from your question

```
with `project.dataset.table` AS (
  select 'Bob' name, 'Interest' question, '["a"]' answer union all
  select 'Sue', 'Interest', '["a", "b"]' union all
  select 'Joe', 'Interest', '["b"]' union all
  select 'Joe', 'Gender', 'Male' union all
  select 'Bob', 'Gender', 'Female' union all
  select 'Sue', 'DOB', '2020-10-17' union all
  select 'Bob', 'Others', '{ "country" : "es", "language" : "ca"}' 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Note: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` part of above script is exactly the same as in previous post - the change is only in preparing original data into temp table `data` and than using it in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

Comment: The above query is giving me the expected results. However, in the "Others" case(JSON object), some of the values are empty JSON strings like `{}`. Because of that the offset is throwing `Array index X is out of bounds (overflow)` error. So I have replaced it with SAFE_OFFSET() and now it's working fine.
How to add a condition to the current query to ignore the empty values?